# How to pre-fill a form and its related inlines with values of another model’s object?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm, django-class-based-views

I have a generic `CreateView` which displays the model and a related ForeignKey model as a form with inlines. Using a similar model with a similar related ForeignKey model as a source - how can i pre-fill the original form and get only the proper amount of inlines according to an object from the source?

The closest i got to a solution is using `CreatWithInlinesView` from [django-extra-views](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) which gives me an empty form with the related model as inlines. But how do i get the data from an existing object of another model into this form with the proper amount of inlines that the object needs?

models.py

```
class Offers(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    …

class OfferDetail(models.Model):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offers, related_name='offerdetails')
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    …

# where the data for prefilling comes from:
class Orders(models.Model):
    reference = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=10)
    …

class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, related_name=‘orderdetails')
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    …
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^offer/(?P<reference>[A-Z]{9})/$', views.MyOfferView.as_view(), name=‘somename’),
```

now if a user visits url `offer/REFERENCE` he should see a form that creates an offer but is pre-filled from the order object that has the reference `REFERENCE`

without pre-filled data from the order object it is working like this (using django-extra-views) 
views.py

```
from extra_views import CreateWithInlinesView, InlineFormSet

class DetailsInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = OfferDetail

class MyOfferView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Offers
    inlines = [DetailsInline, ]
    template_name = ‘someapp/somename.html'
    success_url = ‘/someurl’

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyOfferView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

somename.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    {% for i in inlines %}
        {{ i|crispy }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find this documentation helpful:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values